# Apache and/or MySQL Blown Away Mysteriously

Tags: apache2, mysql, disk-usage

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 under VirtualBox with Windows 10 as the host.  The problem I had has occurred to me twice within 3 days.

I am doing Drupal development work with a fairly large database which I had to occasionally reload. My disk usage is at 75% but later on I see it climbing to as high as 90%.  I try to clean up as much as I can but disk usage is still climbing. Over time, Apache and MySQL are blown away and inoperable. I noticed that /var/log/apache2 folder no longer exists and I cannot even find mysql.lck. In summary files and folders are gone.  I never experienced this before and am new to 20.04.  I never had this problem using 18.04 and will probably rebuild a VM for that.

Right now I import a backup of my VM but as I stated, this problem happened again.  Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've had disk errors before, in which it appeared that entire directory structures went missing.  Have you run a disk check, like `sudo fsck -f /dev/xxxx` to check your partitions?

Mounted partitions cannot be scanned by Ubuntu - the easiest way to check all of your partitions will be to create a live USB - like the one that you use to install Ubuntu - and boot from that.

Since you are using a VM, the method for doing this would be to mount the ISO file for Ubuntu as a cdrom in your VM, and boot from that cdrom.

In either case, choose 'Try Ubuntu' (**not** Install Ubuntu).  At that point you can open a terminal window, and use the commands

```
lsblk
```

or

```
blkid
```

to list the block devices in your system

```
sudo fsck -f /dev/xxxx
```

The purpose behind the option `-f` is to force `fsck` to check the file structure, even if it is marked clean.  This is documented in `man e2fsck`, which is called by `fsck` for ext2/ext3/ext4 file systems

Comment: I suspect it has something to do with the partitions. This is what I got after running your suggestion: `sudo fsck -f /dev/sda5
 fsck from util-linux 2.34
e2fsck 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
/dev/sda5 is mounted.
e2fsck: Cannot continue, aborting.`

Comment: @dotmundo I had meant to put that in a comment, as it is not a full answer.  I will expand upon it, and hopefully we can get you going again.

Answer (score 0):

I lost the /var/log/apache2 which now prevents Apache from working.  In addition I tried to ran blkid and got the following:

dev/sda5: UUID="0046a6d1-a761-4311-8bde-a65eed8ca7e9" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="0531d8f0-05"

I used Vagrant to create this VM. I decided I am going to create a new VM from scratch.